# Parse - Three Columns, One Row

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

So I'm trying to make the email, username, and password columns as one row per user but using this code I created: http://pastebin.com/e8wGNrya it makes each column into a separate row.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't give enough information to understand your problem. Where are you putting those three text fields? Are you trying to make a table view with three columns?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have it in one row, don't create multiple objects :-)
Though for modifying user class in such a way may be not possible, please check documentation or use proper methods to set username, from the example it is not clear what are you trying to do, there is also UI provided for login procedures or method to do so.
However to store multiple columns to one row you may use code like :

`PFObject *userObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"CustomClass"]; //custom class
    userObject[@"username"]= cUserField.text;
    userObject[@"password"]=cPassField.text;
    userObject[@"email"]=cEmailField.text;
    [userObject saveEventually];`